# ActiveXObjects FileSystemObject to Generate Website

Tags: javascript, html, activexobject

This page has 2 text inputs, and 1 button.  When the user clicks the button, the script should do the following:

copy the "template" folder from the current directory into a new directory whose path is determined by the values of the two text inputs.
For example, if the user inputs "foo" and "bar", the program would copy "\template" to the new directory "\foo\bar".

UPDATE:  Newer version almost works, but I have some problem with file paths:

```
<html>
    <body>  

        Company DIR: <input id="companyDIR" "type="text" value="generic"><br>
        State URL: <input id="stateURL" type="text" value=""><br>

        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="Button" id="buildButton" value="Click to build the Link">

            <script>
                var myButton = document.getElementById("buildButton");
                myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    var myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                    myObject.CreateFolder ("C:\\Program Files\\linkbuild\\export\\" + companyDIR.value + "\\" + stateURL.value + "\\");
                    var myObject2;
                    myObject2 = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                    var destination_myObject2 = "C:\\Program Files\\linkbuild\\export\\" + companyDIR.value + "\\" + stateURL.value + "\\";
                    myObject2.CopyFolder("C:\\Program Files\\linkbuild\\template\\*", destination_myObject2);
                });
            </script>

        </form>

        <script>
            document.write("Create Directory: " + stateURL.value );
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `JScript`?  `ActiveXObject`?  This question is a blast from the past.

Comment: You have in your script `companyURL.value` but the actual ID of the field is `companyDIR`, also you have an extra `"` in the HTML: `id="companyDIR" "type="text"` + `id="stateURL" "type="text"`

Comment: That was helpful Alon, but it's still not working.  I think there's a problem with my paths or escape characters.  Going to remove relevant paths for now and see if that lets it work.